# Compare 2 text files and create a 3rd text file where rows are formatted with common strings (adjacent string completion)

Tags: powershell, batch, comparison

I have 2 text files.
**text1.txt** : 
First is structured in this way

```
<title>Developing a wireless </title> ##www.google.com##
<title>Webdriver Actionchains </title> ##www.alfa.com##
<title>Populating a DataGridViewComboBox </title> ##www.beta.com##
```

**text2.txt** 
Second text file is structured like this

```
hhppKJt.png ##www.beta.com##
MchrzjL.zip ##www.google.com##
```

I ask if there is a way create a new ***third*** text file but structured like this

```
<title>Developing a wireless </title> ##www.google.com## MchrzjL.zip
<title>Populating a DataGridViewComboBox </title> ##www.beta.com## hhppKJt.png
<title>Webdriver Actionchains </title> ##www.alfa.com##
```

In other words script (powershell, batch or some comparison program) should check if there is a common string between two text files and after scanning them it should concatenate those specific strings into new rows. 
For example, in both the *first* and *second* text file there are these common strings

```
##www.beta.com##
##www.google.com##
```

if this is true then you should join these string

```
hhppKJt.png
MchrzjL.zip
```

enriching relative rows of first text file in this way

```
<title>Developing a wireless </title> ##www.google.com## MchrzjL.zip
<title>Populating a DataGridViewComboBox </title> ##www.beta.com## hhppKJt.png
<title>Webdriver Actionchains </title> ##www.alfa.com##
```

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  C=0;
}
{
  if (ARGIND == 1) {
     X = $NF
     T0[$NF] = C++
     $NF = ""
     T1[X] = $0
  } else {
     X = $NF
     T0[$NF] = C++
     $NF = ""
     T2[X] = $0
  }
}

END {
  for (X in T0) {
    print T1[X],X,T2[X]
  }
}
```

Put all of the above in a script, eg.  join.sh, and make this script executable.  Call the script with two filenames as parameters, eg.:

```
./join.sh text1.txt text2.sh
```

Trying to cater for m:n ratios:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk  -f

BEGIN {
  OFS=FS=";"
  C=0;
}
{
  if (ARGIND == 1) {
     X = $NF
     T0[$NF] = C++
     $NF = ""
     if (T1[X]) {
        T1[X] = T1[X] $0
     } else {
        T1[X] = $0
     }
  } else {
     X = $NF
     T0[$NF] = C++
     $NF = ""
     if (T2[X]) {
        T2[X] = T2[X] $0
     } else {
        T2[X] = $0
     }
  }
}

END {
  for (X in T0) {
    # concatenate T1[X] and X, since T1[X] ends with ";"
    print T1[X]  X, T2[X]
  }
}
```

Comment: mm, I never used awk. Where do I add path of text1.txt and text2.txt?  Maybe between quotes of `$NF = ""` ?

Comment: No, on the command line, arguments 1 and 2.  (ARGIND 1 = text1.txt, ARGIND 2 = text2.txt).

Comment: Do you mean replace `if (ARGIND == 1)  {` into `if (ARGIND 1 = text1.txt) {`? I have 2 files text to compare, why in your script you write only one argument `ARGIND == 1` ? For example, I need to replace `T2[X] = $0` into `text2.txt[X] = $0`? Could you show me your script filled with text1.txt and text2.txt ?

Comment: I test your script but there are 2 problems: I don't see *text3.txt* because text is only displayed on command prompt (I use awk in windows) and is not exported. Second problem you can see here https://pastebin.com/my1hi1aT - If you have different names for same link your script doesn't work, or better, works only for ratio **1:1** and not for other ration, for example **10** different names: **1** link

Comment: @Gerald H. Pille   In my example I change delimitator and I choose `;` -  seems that also don't work if I reverse order between `name:link` instead of `link:name`

Comment: P.S: the command that I use is `awk -f ./join.sh text1.txt text2.txt`

Comment: "I don't see text3.txt".  Add  " > text3.txt"  to your command.   For the rest of your comments: my script was based on your examples.  No 1:m ratios, no other delimiters, no reverse order.  I think awk can handle all these, but you should have asked immediately.

Comment: ok, thank you very much

Comment: The problem with the field separator may be quite easy to solve, just add these parameters " -F ';' " or " --field-separator ';' ".

Comment: Added a possible solution for m:n ratios.

Comment: Please do not answer off topic questions as it encourages other users to just ask for code without making any attempt to solve it themselves.